# I am passing data to the recycleView in reverse order. But I got an error somewhere

Tags: java, android, kotlin, adapter, recycle

I am passing data to the recycleView in reverse order. The xmn part of my code has a recycleView inside a recycleView. But when he draws the 2nd item, he freezes? Am I making a mistake somewhere?

[You can get my project from this link. I just want to get it right](https://github.com/Jamshid2606/MultipleRecycleView)

I am passing data to the recycleView in reverse order. The xmn part of my code has a recycleView inside a recycleView. But when he draws the 2nd item, he freezes? Am I making a mistake somewhere?

[You can get my project from this link. I just want to get it right](https://github.com/Jamshid2606/MultipleRecycleView)

Comment: Please, add the code causing the error here. Providing also the stack trace will help.